# How do I use static field for function in change detection cycle in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I want to use a static field instead of calling the function isCorrect(option.correct, i) on every CD cycle in my template. Please can you help me to do this. Thank you.

My template's code looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <ol *ngIf="!multipleAnswer">
    <div class="options" *ngFor="let option of currentQuestion.options; index as i">
      <mat-radio-button
        (change)="setSelected(i)"
        [class.is-correct]="option.selected && option.correct"
        [class.is-incorrect]="option.selected && !option.correct">

        <li>{{ option.text }}</li>

        <mat-icon class="feedback-icon" *ngIf="option.selected && option.correct && isCorrect(option.correct, i)">done
        </mat-icon>
        <mat-icon class="feedback-icon" *ngIf="option.selected && !option.correct">clear</mat-icon>
      </mat-radio-button>

      <section class="messages" *ngIf="option.selected">
        <div *ngIf="option.selected && option.correct && isCorrect(option.correct, i)">
          <mat-icon class="sentiment">sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="message correct-message">
              You&apos;re right! {{ correctMessage }}
            </span>
        </div>
...
```

Comment: What does your isCorrect method do? You already have a correct property on your option object.

Comment: It returns a boolean that checks if the selected optionIndex is equal to the correct option:   isCorrect(correct: boolean, optionIndex: number): boolean {
    return correct === this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex].correct;
  }

Comment: Isn't it always true? And if it's not, you can just set another variable in your `onChange` method that you can use in your template instead of calling that method

Comment: Yes I believe it is. Never mind then... I am using (change)="setSelected(i)" where I check if the selected answer index is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, it's not really a static field that you need. You just need a variable on your component, or one of the options, to know if that option is correct.

From the code you provided in your comment, I think your `ìsCorrect` method will always return true, so you can directly use `option.correct` instead of `isCorrect(option.correct, i)`

If that `isCorrect` method really does some tricky logic, you can call that method in your `setSelected` method, which is called whenever the selection changes. Or you can set a component variable and use it in the template

```
class MyComponent
{
    public correct: isCorrectAnswerSelected = false;
    //...
    setSelected()
    {
     this.isCorrectAnswerSelected = this.isCorrect(... );
```

**template**

```
<div *ngIf="option.selected && option.correct && isCorrectAnswerSelected">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static field inside a function:

```
export class YourComponent {

    static correct = true;

    isCorrect(){
        return YourComponent.correct;  
    }

    // or this:
    get ok() {
        return YourComponent.correct;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: ok I've added the static field and changed my function isCorrect as follows: isCorrect(correct: boolean, optionIndex: number): boolean {
    return QuizQuestionComponent.correct && correct === this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex].correct;
  } but not sure what to replace the function calls with in the view template...

Comment: I think I  missunderstood. Can you show us the template? Do you have a list in your template and you want to show the correct-status of each item?

Comment: Yes that sounds like what I have. Please see my template above.